# Delete records from a table where < max number for a field and keep highest number

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I know this sounds rather confusing but I'm at a loss how to explain it better. I have a table simplified below:

```
DB Type       ID
================
Table1         1                 
Table1         2                 
Table1         3                 
Table1         4                 
Table1         5                 
Table2         6                 
Table2         7                 
Table2         8                 
Table2         9                 
Table2        10
```

what i am trying to achieve is to basically clean out this table but keep the record with the highest ID for each DB Type if that makes sense - so in this case it would be (Table1,5) and (Table2,10) with all other records being deleted. Is it possible to do this exclusively through MySQL?

****EDIT******

Answer thanks to tips from Yogendra Singh

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(ID) from MyTable GROUP BY DB Type) AS tb1 ) ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY selecting the max `ID` group by `db_type` first and then use it as sub query with `not in`.

```
 DELETE FROM MyTable 
 WHERE ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT ID FROM 
      (SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID from MyTable GROUP BY DB Type) AS tb1
    )
```

EDIT:

```
 DELETE FROM MyTable
 HAVING MAX(ID) > ID;
```

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing i had in mind but couldnt think on it, unfortunately getting this error  -[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'MyTable' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @JazziJeff: Try with `having` clause and let me know, if doesn't work.

Comment: Just tried a work around and this works   DELETE FROM MyTable
 WHERE `ID` NOT IN (SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT MAX(`ID`) from MyTable GROUP BY `DB Type`) AS tb1
   )
ORDER BY `ID` ASC     it seems your edit may remove all records for other dbtypes?  but never the less thanks for your help this put me on right line of thought!!

Comment: @JazziJeff: It will not as I am using condition as `MAX(ID) > ID;`. It would have been `=` then yes. I just answered another question of similar nature as this creates a temporary table on the fly for you.

Comment: Thanks yogendra, i'll give it a try as it looks a lot cleaner and simpler :)

Comment: @JazziJeff: I updated the answer with your working query for other's help.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete your_table
from
  your_table left join
  (select max(id) max_id from your_table group by type) mx
  on your_table.id=mx.max_id
where mx.max_id is null
```

Subquery returns the maximum id for every type, and those are the values to keep. With an left join i'm selecting all the rows from your table that don't have an in in max_ids, and those are the rows to delete. This will work only if id is primary key, otherwise we have to join also the type.

Answer (score 1):

Is the combination DB Type - ID unique?

If so, you can attack this in two stages:

1. Get only the rows you want

   ```
   SELECT [DB Type], Max(ID) AS MaxID
   FROM YourTable
   GROUP BY [DB Type]
   ```
2. Delete the rest (Wrapping the previous statement into a more complicated statement; don't mean that)

   ```
   DELETE FROM YourTable
   FROM
       YourTable
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT [DB Type], Max(ID) AS MaxID
        FROM YourTable GROUP BY [DB Type]) DontDelete
       ON
         YourTable.[DB Type]=DontDelete.[DB Type] AND
         YourTable.ID=DontDelete.MaxID
   WHERE
     DontDelete.[DB Type] IS NULL
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM MyTable del
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM MyTable xx
     WHERE xx."db Type" = del."db Type"
     AND xx.id > del.id
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from my_Table  
 where Day in (select  MAX(day) d from my_Table   where id='id')
```