# How would I limit the number of table rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have a simple table with the columns:

```
date - DATETIME
name - varchar(50)
text - varchar(200)
```

How can I get the row containing the oldest date value to delete just before an 11th row is added, so the number of rows is always 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Triggers

`create  TRIGGER trigger_name before insert on table_name
 FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN 
 if count  > 10 then 
 delete from table_name
 insert into table_name values(id, name , quantity);
 END if;
 END ;`

you can also refer to this link
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 0):

Create post delete trigger with delete query as:

```
     //get the row count
     IF rowCount > 10
       DELETE from myTable
       WHERE date = 
        (select date from 
          (select date from myTable
          order by date asc LIMIT 1) as tempTable
        )
      END IF;
```

I am advising this because same table condition in delete query doesn't work. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609943/delete-records-from-a-table-where-max-number-for-a-field-and-keep-highest-numb/13610007#13610007) is my another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update the oldest row instead of doing an `insert`+`delete`? You'll need to make sure there are 10 rows in the table to start with of course.